# a:active selector not applied on image links in ie

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

Given this hyperlink formatting:

```
a        { display: block; margin: 10px; border: 2px solid black }
a:hover  { border-color: green }
a:active { border-color: red   }​
```

Then, have some markup:

```
<a href="">text</a>
<a href=""><img src="http://dummyimage.com/300x20"/></a>
<a href="">text</a>​
```

**IE9, Y U NO :ACTIVE ON IMAGE LINKS?**

(try here: http://jsfiddle.net/Vutj8/8/)

Comment: What cclor is it when active or hover? (On a tablet, so I can't see)

Comment: It's green on `active` and `hover`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
a:active, a:focus { border-color: red   }​
```

Comment: So close (red on active), but not quite (still red when no more active).

Comment: Try to add `a:visited {border-color:black}`.

Comment: Still no red border on active.